# Bash script to compile and copy the aar lib to app

Tags: android, bash, shell

I have never written a bash script before and I was hoping that you guys could assist me in writing one to do the following.

I have an Android `Lib` which needs to be copied to an Android app. I am currently still working on the Lib and ironing out some bugs so I need to make quite a few edits in the Lib and it is becoming very tedious to do so as I need to compile, then rename and copy the lib very often.

The steps the script needs to follow:

1. Delete the file (if exists) `~/home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar`
2. run `~/home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar/./gradlew assembleRelease`
3. rename the file to `tsslib.aar`
4. go to the directory `~/home/StudioProjects/fitment_manager/tsslib/`
5. delete the file `tsslib.aar` in the preceding directory
6. copy the newly created `tsslib` from `/home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar/` to `/home/StudioProjects/fitment_manager/tsslib/`

I have never done this before and any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have waisted everyone's time this was much easier than expected. I have some knowledge in writing Batch files in Windows so took a similar approach and it worked for me!

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script is created to remove manual compile and copy of the TSSLib to the Android App

#Delete file tsslib.aar in folder/home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar
rm -f /home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar/tsslib.aar

#Delete the file tsslib.aar in the folder /home/StudioProjects/fitment_manager/tsslib/
rm -f /home/StudioProjects/fitment_manager/tsslib/tsslib.aar

#Change directory to /home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/
#Run ./gradlew assembleRelease which creates the file tsslib-release.aar
cd /home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/
./gradlew assembleRelease

#Rename and move the file to tsslib.aar in /home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/
mv /home/StudioProjects/tsslib_v2/tsslib/build/outputs/aar/tsslib-release.aar /home/StudioProjects/fitment_manager/tsslib/tsslib.aar

#output message that script has completed
echo "Prepare has been completed with 0 errors"
```

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: For the record, this is a really bad way of handling projects dependencies, totally dependent of the machine and environnement, not integrated and not practical. As a matter of facts, even the "relative path dependency" solution I proposed was not perfect, the actual solution intended by the gradle environment would be to publish the lib to a maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem, but not the answer to your question, if you still want the bash script feel free to ask and I'll edit to add it.

The simplest solution to your problem is simply to use the module feature of Android Studio, since the `lib` and `app` are two Android Studio projects (so also modules), you simple have to reference the `lib module` in your `app project` and use it as a dependency in your `app module` :

- Reference your `lib module` from your `app project` by adding it into the app project `settings.gradle` file

  ```
  include ':lib-module-name'
  project(':lib-module-name').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'path-to-your-lib-project/lib-module-name')
  //With the paths you gave :
  include ':tsslib'
  project(':tsslib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../tsslib_v2/tsslib')
  ```
- Synch the project with gradle files, the lib should appear in the project explorer.
- Add the newly imported module as a dependency of your `app` module, in your app `build.gradle`

  ```
  compile project(':lib-module-name')
  //With the paths you gave :
  compile project(':tsslib')
  ```

Therefore, every time you compile the app, it will compile the lib aswell. It also enables you to develop your lib all along with a single opened Android Studio project, keeping files where they were.